# Need confirmation of possible VS 2010 IDE Bug (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, ide

I need a few people to test the below testcase in VS 2010 and VS 2010 Express and please let me know if I am experiencing a possible (and highly annoying) IDE/Code Editor bug.

Create a new VB Project and make it a Windows Form application and add a new module to the project.  In the module, paste the below code:

```
Public Sub Bug()  
    Dim Ninja As Object = Nothing  
    Dim Pirate As Object = Nothing
    If (Not Ninja Is Nothing) AndAlso (Not Pirate Is Nothing) Then _
        Call String.Join(","c, {"one",
                        "two", "three"})
End Sub
```

Now, position the cursor **before** the opening double quote in the word `"two"`.  Press the tab key **one time**, and then press either the **up arrow** or **down arrow**.

If the bug fires, that entire line of text will be deleted.  It will **not** fire if the `If` block is omitted, or the `If` block uses a closing `End If` (instead of just the line continuation character).

I am experiencing this on VS2010 Express (VB.NET version).  I'll have to try it in VS2010 Premium at work to verify there.  I suspect that, if it is a genuine bug, it's in Intellisense, cause the up/down keys usually trigger that to pop up with suggestions.  Maybe it gets confused and just deletes the line somehow?

I thought my project file was corrupted, but I tested this in a brand new project and it still triggers.

If it is a bug, where do we report these things?

Comment: It seems related to not using a line continuation character (a new feature in VS2010 I think) inside of array curly braces while attempting to use a one-line `If` statement simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, i've no previous experience with the bug. A quick search on the MS Connect site did not find any existing feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm the bug in VS2010 Ultimate Edition.
The line gets deleted. Also when I use backspace instead of tab.

You can report the bug on http://connect.microsoft.com under visual studio

Marcel

Comment: Likewise, experiencing this with VS2010 Ultimate as well.  As Kumba mentioned above, adding an underscore seems to prevent that. Removing the first underscore and adding an "End If" also seems to get around it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll figure out how to report this on Connect later on.  Good to know!

Comment: If you post a link to your connect entry, we can vote upon it (on the connect site i mean :) ).